# How to start Microsoft Edge in InPrivate mode from command line

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have searched a lot to open Microsoft Edge in InPrivate mode. I could not find out the solution. How to start Microsoft Edge in InPrivate mode from command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User [ウィンドウズスクリプトプログラマ](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6%E3%82%BA%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9E/?ws=usercard-mini) over on the Microsoft Scripting Forum gave this command line:

```
cmd.exe /c start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge -private
```

which works for me on Windows Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.850) and Version 1709 (OS Build 16229.125).

**Update:** This no longer works as at Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0 on Windows Version 1809.

**Update:** For Microsoft Edge Version 91.0.864.67 on Window 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1083) (as tested) you can use:

```
start msedge.exe www.stackoverflow.com -inprivate
```

or, from a PowerShell prompt:

```
Start-Process msedge.exe -ArgumentList "-inprivate"
```

Comment: When I enter the above in my win10 October 2018 1809 (OS Build 17764.194) install it takes me to a new tab in my existing running instance of edge with my default search engine returning results for "-private".  Is this still working for others?

Comment: doesn't work any more

Comment: @MudasarRauf Thank you for commenting on that; now that I have a computer which can actually install 1809, I can confirm it myself. I have updated the answer in light of that.

Comment: You can also try `start msedge.exe www.stackoverflow.com -inprivate`

Comment: @SonPham Thank you, I edited that information into the answer with the version numbers I have available to test it with.

Answer (score 6):

I talked to the Microsoft Program Manager about this and inprivate+command line is not available at this time.

I did note there is a feature suggestion in for this at https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9245247-inprivate-command-line-switch .  Anyone interested or desiring this feature could "vote it up".

Sorry I can't do more.  I did 'vote it up' for you.  Healy in Tampa