# Launch Microsoft Edge in private/incognito mode in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-edge, process.start

Just a quick question. Anybody have an idea for how to launch Microsoft Edge *in private or incognito* mode in .Net.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com");
```

works perfect, but I can't figure out how to do it in private/incognito mode.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**
I'm not allowed to use 3rd party lib's.

Comment: Edge doesn't actually seem to support this.

Comment: add a `-private` argument after your url. E.g. `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com -private");` Please do note it isn't the same for each browser. They all have their own argument

Comment: @Scircia Thanks for your comment. However Process.Start just thinks that " -private" is part of the URL http://www.google.com%20-private/

Comment: @Viking add this as an *argument*. The first parameter of `Process.Start` is the command, the second are the arguments

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks a lot, but `Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com", "-private")` dosen't work either. Edge is launched opening google.com, but not in private mode.

Comment: You're not allowed to configure the edge beforehand? like thru the browser properties and set the browser to always open `in-private`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code works for me:

Process.Start(@"msedge.exe", @"--InPrivate [https://stackoverflow.com/"](https://stackoverflow.com/%22));

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to do it using the W3C Webdriver API. More details can be seen on the following page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. And sorry for not specifying it earlier, but I'm not allowed to use 3rd party lib's

Comment: @Viking that's not a 3rd party library. It's provided by Microsoft. It may be too much if all you want is to just launch a browser though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry I wasn't more specific, but I'm not allowed to use any assemblies not provided in .Net 4.5

Comment: @Viking that's nor entirely correct, otherwise you wouldn't be able to write *any* code - .NET 4.x extracted several libraries into NuGet packages, so you *need* to add those just to be able to run your application. Besides, .NET 4.5 is unsupported for several years now. The oldest supported version is 4.5.2. .NET 4.x runtimes are binary replacements, so you can't run on 4.5 even if you want to, any security Windows Update patches would replace it with the latest binary version

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [selectable .Net version](https://postimg.cc/8s0bGtL5) No NuGet.

Comment: @Viking You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio#add-the-newtonsoftjson-nuget-package) about how to add NuGet.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this Code could solve your Problem.

```
    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("InPrivate", true);
    this.edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

EDIT: It's from Selenium

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. And sorry for not specifying it earlier, but I'm not allowed to use 3rd party lib's

Comment: Those aren't part of .NET or any of the common NuGet packages. Where does `EdgeOptions` come from? Selenium?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for the unspecific answer and yes it's from Selenium.

Comment: @daniboomberger No problem. And thanks for taking the time to provide an answer. Although I'm not able to use your suggested solution, I'm sure others will.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched a lot of information, it seems that there's no way to launch Microsoft Edge in pravite using only C# for now. You could refer to these links: [link1](https://superuser.com/questions/998488/can-microsoft-edge-be-launched-in-private-mode-through-cmd), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308174/how-to-start-microsoft-edge-in-inprivate-mode-from-command-line), [link3](https://www.tenforums.com/browsers-email/141958-how-do-i-create-edge-browser-open-private-mode.html#post1739608). All the methods are not working since Windows Version 1809.

So I think the only workaround is using Edge Webdriver like [this sample](https://github.com/M-Yankov/SeleniumNetCore/blob/master/src/SampleWebForQA.UI.Tests/EdgeTests.cs). If you can't use webdriver then I think there's no options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I've reached to same conclusion. Only issue is that I’m not allowed to use 3rd party assemblies sush as OpenQA

Answer (score 0):

This code works on .NET 6:

```
Process process = new Process(); 
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; 
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msedge";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-inprivate \"https://stackoverflow.com/\""; 
process.Start();
```